# 1- Make a library in C 2- Call and use it in MASM

Tags: c, masm

The teacher asked to do the two tasks given in the title,and the only hint he gave is that the library file will have extension ".lib" . I have tried to make a static library using Code Blocks, and it has ".a" extension instead of .lib. Now how do I call and use this library in MASM, I have no idea. Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

A `.a` file is a static library on Linux / UNIX. Code Blocks is cross-platform, but often found on Linux, so I wouldn't be surprised if you were running it there.

A `.lib` file is a static library on Windows. MASM is the Microsoft (Windows) assembler.

You're not using the right toolchain for your platform. Or potentially, you're not even working on the right platform.

Comment: I am using Windows, and Code Blocks gave me '.a' file. Now once I have either '.a' or '.lib', how do I call & use it in MASM,any idea?